# python with firebase cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, python-3.7

hello I’m using firebase in python and I want it to connect to cloud firestore and I found this tutorial but I don’t know how he called if to his data base.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wlr8jMehNQ0&t=382s

Comment: what have you tried? always include some code

Comment: yes I tried. When in the video it already puts data inside the database in mine does not work. I don’t know where I can get the ```credentials.Certificate``` ?